# Assignment raises exception for list.index

Tags: python

How could this code fragment...

```
def subInPath(origPath, subPath):
    origSplit = split(origPath, '/')
    subSplit = split(subPath, '/')

    subRoot = subSplit[0]
    origSplit.reverse()
    print origSplit.index(subRoot)
    rootIndex = origSplit.index(subRoot)

    origSplit[:rootIndex+1] = []
    origSplit.reverse()

    newPath = join(origSplit, sep)
    newPath += (sep + subPath)

    if not exists(newPath):
        raise Exception, "Path subbed in not found."
    return newPath
```

with the arguments `("C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/second_stage/Kickle_Pack/GardenLand_D.xml", "Kickle_Pack/Animations/TileAnims_48x48.xml")`...

Output `2` at the print statement, but throw a `ValueError` at the statement below it. I'm baffled.

Comment: does the error specifically say `x not in list`?

Comment: also, where are you getting the `split` function? am I correct in assuming that it returns a list?

Comment: I don't get the same results as you. Can you please complete your code with the necessary import statements and the exact call to subInPath() so that it is possible to run the code in the same way you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `os.path` module when working with directories or paths. It's got all the methods needed to work with directories, plus it has the advantage of being compatible in multiples operating system.

It's just better software engineering.

Comment: I wasn't able to find what I am trying to accomplish via it.

Comment: Fixed, was an issue with the os.sep at the bottom.

Comment: @random if you are working with paths & directory structures, then os.path is the module for you. Please read the documentation, you'll get what you need.

Comment: Yes I did, I tried, and I completely agree with you. However I wasn't able to find what I needed to accomplish (well I'm sure I could have used what I found to accomplish it, but it would have been going around the mulberry bush). Also, note that I am not able to use any of the functions that aren't cross-platform (there are several in the os.path module). This gets the job done, and in the end that is what matters (though I definitely do agree with you, and if you know of a cleaner way via that module let me know).

Comment: @random: """Fixed, was an issue with the os.sep at the bottom""" ??? The mention of `sep` (*not* `os.sep`) is *AFTER* the `origSplit.index(subRoot)` lines!!! Please explain.